# View contents of a file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running this command:

```
hadoop fs -ls /tej/
```

This is the output:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup   19 2016-02-19 18:46 /tej/t1.txt
```

Could you please tell me how to display the contents present in `t1.txt`?

I tried the `cat` command but couldn't display the content present in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to see the content of a file is `hadoop fs -cat /path/to/your/file`. In the path, you have to provide the path to file and not folder. I think you used `hadoop fs -cat /tej/` that will not work.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to create a file inside the directory in hadoop

Comment: Here is the command : hadoop fs -mkdir /m1

m1 is the newly created directory ,Could you please tell me how to create a file say file1.txt inside m1..

Thanks,
Tejashwini

Comment: What kind of file? You can put your file from local file system to HDFS by `hadoop fs -put /path/to/your/local/file /path/to/destination/on/hdfs`

Comment: Create your file in your local file system and insert the content. Then, put it in HDFS via the command I said above.

Comment: Could you please let me know the jars for hadoop map reduce program..

Hadoop version :-2.7.1

Thanks,
Tejashwini

Comment: Please upvote my answer. You can run a sample mapreduce program by this command: `hadoop jar /path/to/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar path/to/input path/to/output`

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Just click on the up arrow near the answers.

Comment: Sorry my question was regarding  what are the jars to be used  for hadoop map reduce program and not the command to execute map reduce program..Could you please let me know..

Comment: Primarily, those are: `hadoop-common.jar`, `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar` and `hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar`

Comment: Create a new question.

Comment: Create a new chat then.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few options...

View tail:

```
hadoop fs -tail /tej/t1.txt
```

View head:

```
hadoop fs -cat /tej/t1.txt | head
```

View entire file:

```
hadoop fs -cat /tej/t1.txt
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the jars for hadoop map reduce program..

Hadoop version :-2.7.1

Thanks,
Tejashwini

Comment: Look, you marked this the answer then revoked it and marked the other answer because he answered more of your questions in the (very long) comment thread. It's clear you've done no research on Hadoop or how to use it at all. This site is about people helping you learn when you get stuck, not about spoon feeding others. If you want to learn Hadoop, start [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop).